Stop Emacs from translating variants of Greek letters in shortcuts
I have an extended keyboard layout with both variants of phi, φ and ϕ. I'd like to use both of them in keybindings, but if I put, say, both C-φ and C-ϕ into a keymap, C-ϕ is translated into C-φ and the binding on C-ϕ is overridden. Moreover, I can't find a keymap that houses these bindings, they are not in iso-transl-ctl-x-8-map or key-translation-map. Moreover, if I try to use key-translate to translate C-ϕ into something else, like (key-translate "C-ϕ" "C-á") I get a wrong-type-argument characterp-error, I assume because ϕ is not in ascii. How can I stop Emacs from translating C-ϕ into C-φ?
Edit: please note that ϕ is not the capital version of φ, its capital version would be Φ. Moreover, Emacs recognizes C-ϕ as different from C-φ, as (kbd "C-ϕ") gives 67109845 while (kbd "C-φ") gives 67109830.

key-translate is for translating characters. You probably want to make an entry in key-translation-map instead to translate "C-ϕ" to "C-á" . How are you putting the two phi bindings into a keymap? It seems to work ok here.

By default, Emacs maps upper case key sequences to lower case sequences for bindings if there is no binding for the upper case sequence. Observe that:
(upcase ?φ) => Φ
(upcase ?ϕ) => Φ

so emacs maps C-ϕ to C-φ, since it checks the binding for C-Φ. To disable this, customize translate-upper-case-key-bindings to nil.
(you could argue this particular case is a bug, but the place to do that is M-x report-emacs-bug)
